# python socket keepalive setting

Tags: python, sockets, tornado, keep-alive

I am doing asynchronous networking programming with tornado, I've created a socket

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
```

and put it in tornado iostream

```
iostream = tornado.iostream.IOStream(sock)
```

I wonder if I could set the socket 'keepalive' after then? Is the setting still valid after the iostream creation. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it's usually best to set any socket options you want before creating the IOStream, but in most cases it's fine to set it afterwards as well (as long as the underlying socket option can be set on a socket that is already connected).  As of Tornado 4.0 the only option IOStream touches directly is TCP_NODELAY.